# pygame.display.toggle_fulscreen() not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, fullscreen, traceback

so, I have tried to get python to toggle into fullscreen, now I thought that all i need to do was:

```
screen=pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()
```

I thought that was good enough
but then it gives me this `traceback` error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pert/PycharmProjects/pygame/fullscreen.py", line 6, in <module>
    screen=pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()
pygame.error
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about your code ?
Is it full error traceback?

Comment: nope, it's only line 6 (the toggle fulscreen line)

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of [`pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen):

> Switches the display window between windowed and fullscreen modes. **This function only works under the UNIX X11 video driver.**

A workaround is presented on the Pygame Wiki [`toggle_fullscreen`](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/toggle_fullscreen?parent=CookBook)

Comment: so, does that mean that i can only use this function on the unix X11 driver?

Comment: @pertifiedchicken Yes. (In a minimal example, it doesn't work on my Windows system)